# Tikz calendar formatting, anchoring text (was small caps, text allignment, and color alternation)

Tags: horizontal-alignment, text-decorations, tikz-calendar

*I have kludged a fix to the small caps and alternating color requirement for the day headings. My code now reflects those changes, and I describe them at the end of this question for those who may be interested.*

**However, there are still two items I am struggling to accomplish.**

(1) I would like the weekday-names to align flush left in their column rather than centered. I feel I should be able to accomplish this by adjusting anchors, but of labels, the calendar, or something else, I don't know.

(2) Also, on either side of the month name, I would like the year written, aligned with the rightmost text and leftmost text respectively.(That is, the initial 2018 flush left with the weekdays, and the 8 in the second year number aligning with the last daynumber, e.g., in January, the 8 above the 9 in 29. (I have used hspace and xshift in the example, but since each monthname is a different length, a fixed space or shift will not work.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 2.5cm, landscape]{geometry}
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calendar, positioning}

\makeatletter
\tikzstyle{week list}=[
    execute before day scope={%
        \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}
            {% On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@xshift}
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
            }
        }{}
},
    execute at begin day scope={%
        \ifodd\pgfcalendarcurrentday\relax \color{red} \fi %%% <-- added line to alternate number colors {thanks to Hood Chatham}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgf@y=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday\pgf@y%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}%
        },
   execute after day scope={%
        \ifdate{Sunday}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
        }{}%
    },
    % % According to Berteun the following should be defined:
    % << tikz@lib@cal@width=7 >>. (I don't know why.)
    ]

    \tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
    \tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
    \tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}
        \foreach \d/\l in {
    0/\sc{Monday},1/\sc\textcolor{red}{Tuesday},     % <----------------------- |
    2/\sc{Wednesday},3/\sc\textcolor{red}{Thursday},    % <----- modified lines |
    4/\sc{Friday},5/\sc\textcolor{red}{Saturday},6/\sc{Sunday}}{     % <------- |
% had been: {0/Monday,1/Tuesday,2/Wednesday,
%            3/Thursday,4/Friday,5/Saturday,6/Sunday} {
        \pgf@ya=\d\pgf@ya%
        \pgftransformxshift{-\pgf@xa}%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}%
        \node[every day, day heading, anchor = base]{\l};%
            }
        }{}%
    }%
]
\makeatother

\newcommand{\calyear}{2018}
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{\calendar[dates = \calyear-#1-01 to \calyear-#1-last];}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style = {
        month label above centered,
        month text = {\Large \%y- \hspace{.5cm} \textsc{\%mt} \hspace{.5cm} \%y- },
        week list,
        day letter headings,
        day heading/.style={xshift=-2cm} % <--- modified line
        % had been: day heading/.style={red, xshift=-2cm}
    }]
    \matrix (Calendar) [column sep = 4em, row sep = 3em] {
        \mon{01} & \mon{02} & \mon{03} \\
        \mon{04} & \mon{05} & \mon{06} \\
        \mon{07} & \mon{08} & \mon{09} \\
        \mon{10} & \mon{11} & \mon{12} \\ };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

*To get the names of the weekdays to be printed in small caps, alternating between black and red, I inserted commands for small caps and red text into the line where the text of the day headings were originally given; I also removed `[red]` from the style definition of `day heading/.style` since changing the default black to red three times required fewer color changes (three to red vs. four to black). The relevant lines now read:*

```
\foreach \d/\l in {
    0/\sc{Monday},1/\sc\textcolor{red}{Tuesday},2/\sc{Wednesday},
    3/\sc\textcolor{red}{Thursday},4/\sc{Friday},
    5/\sc\textcolor{red}{Saturday},6/\sc{Sunday}}
```

*and*

```
day heading/.style={xshift=-2cm}
```

*I'm sure there is a better way to accomplishing this rather than "hard-wiring" for each instance of a day heading -- but the kludge works.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a few changes: I assume you want the calendar to be centered on the page both vertically and horizontally. To do this, I set the margins to be zero and use the `\centering` command to horizontally center. To vertically center the calendar, I say `\let\@texttop\vfill\let\@textbottom\vfill`.

Instead of manually entering each weekday in the loop to create the weekdays, you can use `\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\d}` where `\d` is the day of the week. To make the odd days red, add `\ifodd\d \color{red}\fi` before this.

To get the days to be aligned left, you need to specify the `text width`, which will make the node a fixed width rectangle and align the text to the left inside of it. The longest weekday name is Wednesday so we say `text width = width("Wednesday")`.

To get the length of the heading correct, we need to already know the width of the month. `pgfcalendar` places the `month label` before it draws the rest of the calendar, which is inconvenient for this. Instead, I place the month heading in the `\mon` macro after the rest of the month is drawn. Then we can find the distance between the west anchor of a day node and the east anchor of the node for the last day in the month and set the `textwidth` of the month title to be this (minus a small offset to account for the `inner sep` of the weekday and month nodes).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin = 0cm, landscape]{geometry}
\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{\centering}
\let\@texttop\vfill
\let\@textbottom\vfill
\pagestyle{empty}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calendar, positioning}

\tikzstyle{week list}=[
    execute before day scope={%
        \ifdate{day of month=1}{\ifdate{equals=\pgfcalendarbeginiso}{}
            {% On first of month, except when first date in calendar.
            \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@month@xshift}
            \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
            }
        }{}
},
    execute at begin day scope={%
        \ifodd\pgfcalendarcurrentday\relax \color{red} \fi %%% <-- added line to alternate number colors {thanks to Hood Chatham}
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@y{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgf@y=\pgfcalendarcurrentweekday\pgf@y%
        \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@y}%
        },
   execute after day scope={%
        \ifdate{Sunday}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength{\pgf@x}{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@x}
        }{}%
    },
    % % According to Berteun the following should be defined:
    % << tikz@lib@cal@width=7 >>. (I don't know why.)
    ]

    \tikzoption{day headings}{\tikzstyle{day heading}=[#1]}
    \tikzstyle{day heading}=[]
    \tikzstyle{day letter headings}=[
    execute before day scope={ \ifdate{day of month=1}{%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@ya{\tikz@lib@cal@yshift}%
        \pgfmathsetlength\pgf@xa{\tikz@lib@cal@xshift}%
        \pgftransformxshift{\pgf@xa}
        \foreach \d/\l in {0,...,6}{     % <------- |
            \pgf@ya=\d\pgf@ya%
            \pgftransformxshift{-\pgf@xa}%
            \pgftransformyshift{-\pgf@ya}%
            \node[every day, day heading, anchor = base,text width=width("Wednesday")] (day-\d) {\ifodd\d \color{red}\fi\sc{\pgfcalendarweekdayname{\d}}};%
        }
    }{}}%
]

\newcount\tempcount
\newcommand{\calyear}{2018}
\newcommand{\mon}[1]{
    \calendar (cal) [dates = \calyear-#1-01 to \calyear-#1-last]; 
    % Add the title
    % Get the date of the last day of the month
    \pgfcalendardatetojulian{\calyear-#1-last}{\tempcount}
    \pgfcalendarjuliantodate{\tempcount}{\throwaway}{\throwaway}{\lastday}
    % Find the distance between the west end of the weekday and the east end of the last day of the month
    \pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{day-0}{west}}{\pgfpointanchor{cal-\calyear-#1-\lastday}{east}}
    % The width of the month should be this distance minus some extra padding
    \edef\monthwidth{\the\dimexpr\pgf@x-7pt}
    % Draw the month title
    \node[above left=0em of day-0,above right, text width=\monthwidth] {\Large \calyear\hfill \textsc{\pgfcalendarmonthname{#1}} \hfill \calyear}; 
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[every calendar/.style = {
        week list,
        day letter headings,
        day heading/.style={xshift=-2cm} % <--- modified line
    }]
    \matrix (Calendar) [column sep = 4em, row sep = 3em] {
        \mon{01} & \mon{02} & \mon{03} \\
        \mon{04} & \mon{05} & \mon{06} \\
        \mon{07} & \mon{08} & \mon{09} \\
        \mon{10} & \mon{11} & \mon{12} \\ };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have been unable to compile. The error is: Undefined control sequence. \tikz@text@width ->calendarwidth    1.76     \mon{01}   &   \mon{02}   &   \mon{03} \\

Comment: Sorry, I messed it up in one of the edits. It should be fixed now.

Comment: Runs like a charm. I was hoping I could figure out the error before bothering you again... but I just didn't see it. I also appreciated seeing how to center the tikzpic on the page both horizontally and vertically.